# Car Shuts Off during low RPM and only happens at night or early morning

Tags: electrical, holden

I have a Holden Barlina 2004 VY model v6

I have it for at least 2 years now, but this issue only started to happen two months ago.

As I turn it on, it goes smooth and quietly, but as I drive, approximately 5 to 7 minutes down the road, when the RPM is down, it would then shuts off without notice, or even when I accelerate when lights turn green, it shuts off midway.

NOTED: this only happens during early morning or at night when it's cold, and once it did that, it would not happen again during the ride. According to one of a mechanic, he claimed that it might be an electrical problem.

My question is
How likely that it is an electrical problem?
if it's not
What else could it be and what could I do to resolve it?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to the site. Could you hook up the vehicle to a scanner and [check if there are any DTC's](http://meta.mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/1470/675)?

Answer (score 3):

Based on the symptoms, I'm going to guess that it might be a problem with the **temperature sensor**.

What is supposed to happen is that the engine control unit (ECU) gets a signal from the engine coolant temperature sensor to tell when the engine is warm.  When it's warm, the ECU knows to lean out the fuel mixture.  What I suspect might be happening is that the sensor is bad and the ECU "thinks" the engine is warm before it is and when you ask for acceleration (as when pulling away when the light turns green), the engine isn't getting enough fuel and stalls.

Fortunately, the temp sensor is pretty cheap (around AUS$5) and relatively easily replaced.  On your model car, I believe it's just in front of the inlet manifold toward the top of the engine.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely sounds like a sensor problem. ~Random stalling is often caused by a bad crankshaft or camshaft sensor as the ECU thinks there is a mechanical problem and puts the engine into a safe mode or loses track doesn't have enough information to properly control functions like automatic choke or anti-stall.

As already mentioned this could also be a temperature or lambda (air/fuel ratio) sensor problem.

The first course of action is to get an electronic diagnostic check an independent dealer can usually do this pretty cheaply and replacing a bad sensor in not usually expensive unless it is in an awkward place.

It is not unusual for this sort of problem to be intermittent so it will help if you take detailed notes about the exact symptoms and the conditions in which they occur to help diagnosis.

It is also not unusual for certain makes and models to have specific sensor problems so a good mechanic familiar with your vehicle may be able to diagnose it just from a description of the problem.